# Flask App visible to localhost only

Tags: python, flask, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

Trying to host python flask app on Ubuntu 18.04 vps. I am using python version 3.6 and not using virtual environment since that vps will be used to host one app only.

This is the content of apache2 config file for this app:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName 15.16.541.21
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/psoftware-nis-app/Backend/flask-api/api.wsgi

   <Directory /var/www/psoftware-nis-app/Backend/flask-api>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>
```

Static IP address I provided is of course not real, but in conf it is the real static IP address of the machine that hosts this app.

When I curl `http://localhost/api/test_endpoint` I get a valid response (from vps).

But when I curl `http://15.16.541.21/api/test_endpoint` from my laptop I get:

> Connection timed out

When I execute this:  `nmap -p 80 15.16.541.21` i get:

> Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes,
>   try -Pn

So when i add `-Pn` and execute: `nmap -p 80 18.191.182.118 -Pn` I get:

> Host is up. PORT   STATE    SERVICE 80/tcp filtered http

Is something wrong with my config file? Or any other idea why the app is not visible to outside world?

EDIT:
I have configured main python module, host option is set:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Is your apache server running correctly? Can you access static pages?

Comment: The problem is that this flask app is used as an API only, I don't have any pages. I believe apache2 is set up correctly because the response is correct when i test it with curl targeting localhost, it returns test array. I want to point out that this is my first time hosting flask app and using apache so I might be wrong.

Comment: @Daniel I have added a txt file called test.txt in flask static folder, reloaded apache service and when I use curl for localhost/test.txt I get 404. Does this answer your question?

Comment: The question was, wheter apache is running correctly? I suppose, the problem has nothing to do with Flask.

Comment: @Daniel Do you have any suggestion on how to test that?

Answer (score 2):

By default, flask app is only visible for local access. You need to specify the host option `--host=0.0.0.0` to make it visible for other network.

> Externally Visible Server
>
> If you run the server you will notice that the server is only
>   accessible from your own computer, not from any other in the network.
>   This is the default because in debugging mode a user of the
>   application can execute arbitrary Python code on your computer.
>
> If you have the debugger disabled or trust the users on your network,
>   you can make the server publicly available simply by adding
>   --host=0.0.0.0 to the command line:
>
> flask run --host=0.0.0.0
>
> This tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.

Check this http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#quickstart

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but I doubt this is the problem, I have already configured that:
`if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the problem, since OP is using Apache and not the built-in Flask dev server.